# Only one WFS layer is invoked out of multiple WFS layers

Tags: openlayers, javascript, wfs

How to add multiple WFS layers and get response simultaneously for all with bbox strategy? In my code only one of WFS call is invoked each time. Even I tried adding separate callback function names. I use GeoServer 2.20.4 and OpenLayers 6.14.1 and WFS 2.0. Any suggestions?
I'm trying 7 WFS layers like below with bbox strategy and at a time only one service request is running. Occasionally two request pass to geoserver and first one won't return the complete response, while next request is being performed completely.

```
mymap.sources.airportAllVectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  loader: function (extent, resolution, projection, success, failure) {
    var proj = projection.getCode();

    var url2 = systemVariables.baseurl + 'airport-data?service=WFS&version=2.0.0' + '&request=GetFeature&typeName=dev:Airport&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&format_options=callback:loadFeatures2&srsname=' + proj + '&' +
            'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',' + proj;

    var is_same = mymap.currentExtend.length == extent.length && mymap.currentExtend.every(function (element, index) {
      return element === extent[index];
    });
    // console.log(is_same);
    if (!is_same) {
      mymap.currentExtend = extent;
      $.ajax({
        url: url2,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function success(response) {
          // this.resolution = resolution;
          // console.log(response);
          addAllAirportData(response);
        }
      });
    }
  },
  //        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
  strategy: function strategy(extent, resolution) {
    if (this.resolution && this.resolution != resolution) {
      //                    this.loadedExtentsRtree_.clear();
      mymap.sources.airportAllVectorSource.clear();
    }
    return [extent];
  }
});



mymap.sources.waypointLowAllVectorSource= new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  loader: function (extent, resolution, projection, success, failure) {
    var proj = projection.getCode();

    var url3 = systemVariables.baseurl + 'waypoint-data?service=WFS&version=2.0.0' + '&request=GetFeature&typeName=dev:WaypointLow&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&format_options=callback:loadFeatures3&srsname=' + proj + '&' +
            'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',' + proj;

    var is_same = mymap.currentExtend.length == extent.length && mymap.currentExtend.every(function (element, index) {
      return element === extent[index];
    });
    // console.log(is_same);
    if (!is_same) {
      mymap.currentExtend = extent;
      $.ajax({
        url: url3,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function success(response) {
          // this.resolution = resolution;
           console.log(response);
          addAllWaypointLowData(response);
        }
      });
    }
  },
  //        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
  strategy: function strategy(extent, resolution) {
    if (this.resolution && this.resolution != resolution) {
      //                    this.loadedExtentsRtree_.clear();
      mymap.sources.waypointLowAllVectorSource.clear();
    }
    return [extent];
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: If it's the same WFS server, then it might be server side problem so receiving to many requests in short time.

Comment: @TomazicM Yes, it is using same **geoserver** (WFS server). Is there a way to modify this code to make these requests run one after other?

Comment: On the second thought, it might not be server's fault. In the past I saw similar problems when `jasonp` protocol was used in AJAX call and different AJAX requests used the same `jasonp` name. I'm not familiar with JQuery implementation of AJAX and so can't say if something similar is happening here.